# In d3 how can you format a date with single digits for month and year if they are under t0?

Tags: datetime, d3.js, string-formatting

For example 5/1/18  or 6/9/18

Instead of 05/01/18 and 06/09/18

Answer (score 1):

It is documented in the GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format#locale_format). Specifically `%-` means disable padding.

day of the month: `%-d`

month: `%-m`

combined: `%-d/%-m/%y`